# NgRx: Get data from store but it's undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

dear Stackoverflow Community.

I'm new in NgRx and trying to find out how does it works. I create an app - simple Shop List based on Angular 6, Firebase and NgRx.

I added a couple of items in collection called `Product` and trying to fetch them via ngrx patterns. Seems I did all good - I have fetched items as payload in `GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS` but I can't put them into the view to display, products are undefined. I tried to do in two ways:

```
this.store.select(getProducts).subscribe(products => {
  console.log('products', products); // undefined
});
```

and

```
 this.products = this.store.select(getProducts); // Store
```

In second way I just get a whole Store...
Code below.

product.actions.ts

```
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Product } from '../../models/product.model';

export const GET_PRODUCTS = 'Get_products';
export const GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS = 'Get_products_success';

export class GetProducts implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_PRODUCTS;
  constructor(public payload = '') {}
}

export class GetProductsSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS;
  constructor(public payload?: Product[]) {}
}

export type Actions = GetProducts | GetProductsSuccess;
```

product.reducer.ts

```
import { Product } from '../../models/product.model';
import * as productAction from './products.action';

export interface State {
  products: Product[];
  loading: boolean;
}

export const initialState: State = {
  products: [],
  loading: false,
};

export function ProductsReducer(state: State = initialState, action: productAction.Actions) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case productAction.GET_PRODUCTS:
      return {...state, loading: true};

    case productAction.GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      const test = {...state, products: action.payload, loading: false};
      console.log("test", test);
      return test;

    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

[image]

product.effects.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Action } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Effect, Actions } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

import { Product } from '../../models/product.model';
import * as productAction from './products.action';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap, map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class ProductEffects {

  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private db: AngularFirestore) {}

  @Effect()
  getProducts: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(productAction.GET_PRODUCTS).pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.db.collection<Product>('products').valueChanges()
        .pipe(
          map((payload) => {
            return {
              type: 'Get_products_success',
              payload: payload
            };
          })
        );
      })
    );
}
```

product.selector.ts

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

import { State } from './products.reducer';
import { Product } from '../../models/product.model';

export function getState(state: State): State {
    return state;
}

export function fetchProducts(state: State): Product[] {
    return state.products;
}

export const getProducts = createSelector(getState, fetchProducts);
```

list.component.ts - get and display all products

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Product } from '../../models/product.model';
import * as productActions from '../../store/products/products.action';
import { State } from '../../store/products/products.reducer';
import { getProducts } from '../../store/products/products.selector';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Observable<Product[]>;

  constructor(private store: Store<State>) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new productActions.GetProducts);
    this.store.select(getProducts).subscribe(products => {
      console.log('products', products);
    });

  }

}
```

If you noticed that I'm doing something wrong - don't shy to tell me.
I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: `case productAction.GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return {...state, products: action.payload, loading: false};` you Need to add the `...state` to the return Statement. Otherwise you will not write it into your store, this makes sure that you take your store `...store` and modifies the Parameters **products** and **loading**

Comment: @EnesYalçın yes, you right. I forgot to add it. But result the same as was before. I added a `test` variable and screenshot from console - everything works in reducer, but I still don't get data out of store

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found out

I looked that how else I can make a request my data from store. I found one way, in context of my app it looks like:

```
 this.store.select(state => state).subscribe(data => {
  console.log('data', data);
});
```

And I get in console the object:

```
{ message: { Products: Array[3], loading: false } }
```

What does this message mean? I made a global search and saw that I implemented my reducer in `app.module.ts` as:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({ message: ProductReducer }),
```

So I created a `index.ts` in reducers folder and export a reducer bellow:

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as fromProducts from './products.reducer';

export interface AppState {
    products: fromProducts.ProductState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AppState> = {
    products: fromProducts.productsReducer
};
```

And now in `app.module.ts` it imports as:

```
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers),
```

and now this code is working well:

```
this.store.select(getProducts).subscribe(products => {
  console.log('products', products);
});
```

Comment: Fixed it for me. My store was undefined until I added my `StoreModule.forRoot(reducers)`, which instantiated the store